# Specific way to concatenate/merge logs from different files

Tags: distributed

When an app is generally deployed on several machines, each machine will have its own log file that keeps track of all the requests that come to app that resides on that machine.
Is there anyway where I can have a consolidated look of several log files at one place ?
A small example to better explain the problem:
App is deployed on Machines A,B,C, each having logs logA.log, logB.log, logC.log files. 
I would want to have a consolidated view of all these three log files, which reside in different machines/servers, at one single location.

Answer (score 1):

You could just copy-paste one after the other in one file.

If you want to merge, how would the merge decide what goes after what from the different files?

Even if you have a unified format of starting with time, you would have to make sure the clocks of the machines are synchronized, otherwise the logs will be misaligned when merged.

Comment: Exactly. Say I do a tail -f on each file, I would be getting the last few lines from each file. Will this approach work when I have a number of log files to fetch? Also, what if the log files are populated with data continuously, because the application keeps running. Is there any specific procedure/algorithm that decides how this is handled ?

Comment: I don't see how having more files would make any difference.  If you can achieve your goal concerning two files, you can (at the least) apply the technique to the result of that and the third file (etc.).  If the files are growing continuously and residing on different machines, you will need to have remote access to them (as opposed to copy all to one machine).  If the records are sorted (which would be true for logs on time), you can easily do an n-way merge.

Answer (score 0):

[*Super Speedy Syslog Searcher*](https://crates.io/crates/super_speedy_syslog_searcher) can merge multiple log files into one log file, sorting log messages by datetime.

(assuming you have [rust installed](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install))

```
cargo install super_speedy_syslog_searcher
```

then

```
s4 /remote1/logs /remote2/logs
```

`s4` can recognize many datetime formats.